# картинка с подписью в виде ссылки, при наведении на картинку-текст

Tags: css-animation, hover, bootstrap4

Пытаюсь на bootstrap4 разработать блок: 
Блок картинок с подписью к каждой, при наведении на блок затемняется картинка и у подписи меняется цвет(но не затемняется фоном), а на картинке появляется текст с описанием картинки.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
    
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="http://slaum89.beget.tech/img/400x267/kontr-aj-nerj.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
            </div>
            </a>    
        </div>
        
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="http://slaum89.beget.tech/img/400x267/kontr-aj-nerj.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
            </div>
            </a>    
        </div>
        
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="http://slaum89.beget.tech/img/400x267/kontr-aj-nerj.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
            </div>
            </a>    
        </div>

    </div>
    
    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Результат должен быть примерно как на этой странице при наведении на блоки: https://www.actived.ru/services/

Answer (score 0):

Бутстрап тут не при чем, если что. Все просто:

```css
.card a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.card a img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

.card a .card-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: RGBA(77, 150, 181, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
}

.card a:hover .card-body {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://slaum89.beget.tech/img/400x267/kontr-aj-nerj.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```